# What is the difference between [[Scopes]] and [[Scope]] in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am learning about closure and today I run the VScode debugger to do an experiment and read the internal properties of a function, there i found a property named [[Scopes]] and it seems that there is where JS store the closures of the function. However i have seen a course and articles that say that the internal property that Javascript actually use is called [[Scope]], they do not mention [[Scopes]]. What is the difference?[image]

Comment: This may be implementation-dependent, as it's not part of the EcmaScript specification.

Comment: See https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects which mentions `[[Environment]]`

Comment: Is this something of nodejs/Google Chrome itself? Because when I run the Firefox's debugger I can't see the [[Scopes]] property.